# Index was outside the bounds of the array. While Clearly it wasn't(unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
RowManager.GenerateRow (System.Single hbias, System.Single vbias) (at Assets/Scripts/RowManager.cs:155)
GameManager.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs:38)
The array has five cells and I index it from 0 to 4.
Unity 2021.3.8f LTS

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
class Baze
{
    private byte Start,End;
    public Baze()
    {
        Start = 0;
        End= 0;
    }
    public void SetStart(byte s)
    {
        Start = s;
    }
    public void SetEnd(byte s)
    {
        End = s;
    }
    public byte GetStart()
    {
        return Start;
    }
    public byte GetEnd()
    {
        return End;
    }
    public void Correction()
    {
        if(Start>End)
        {
            byte temp = Start;
            Start = End;
            End = temp;
        }
    }
    public bool isSingular()
    {
        return Start == End;
    }
}
class MazeLogic
{
    private List<SortedSet<byte>> Groups;
    private SortedSet<byte> TempSet;
    private Baze TempRange;
    private List<Baze> Template;
    private uint[] IDs;
    private bool[] Hjoints, Vjoints;
    public MazeLogic()
    {
        Groups = new List<SortedSet<byte>>();
        TempRange = new Baze();
        IDs = new uint[5] {1,2,3,4,5};
        Hjoints = new bool[5] {false,false,false,false,false};
        Vjoints = new bool[5] {true,true,true,true,true};
        TempSet = new SortedSet<byte>();
        Template = new List<Baze>();
        for(byte i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            TempRange.SetStart(i);
            TempRange.SetEnd((byte)(i + 1));
            Template.Add(TempRange);
        }
    }
    private void SetGroups(float bias)
    {
        uint temp = 0;
        for(byte i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            Hjoints[i]= false;
            if (Vjoints[i])
                temp = IDs[i];
            else
                IDs[i] = 0;
        }
        for (byte i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            if (IDs[i] == 0)
                IDs[i] = ++temp;
        TempRange.SetStart(0);
        for(byte i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            if (Random.value > bias && IDs[Template[i].GetStart()] != IDs[Template[i].GetEnd()])
            {
                TempSet.Add(Template[i].GetStart());
                TempSet.Add(Template[i].GetEnd());
            }
            else
            {
                TempSet.Add(Template[i].GetStart());
                Groups.Add(TempSet);
                TempSet.Clear();
            }
        }
        for (byte i = 0; i < Groups.Count; i++)
            for (byte j = Groups[i].Min; j < Groups[i].Max; j++)
                Hjoints[j] = true;
    }
    private void SetVjoints(float bias)
    {
        bool check;
        for (byte i = 0; i < Groups.Count; i++)
        {
            check = false;
            for (byte j = Groups[i].Min; j <= Groups[i].Max; j++)
                if(Random.value>bias)
                {
                    check = true;
                    Vjoints[j] = true;
                }
            if (!check)
                Vjoints[Random.Range(Groups[i].Min, Groups[i].Max + 1)] = true;
        }
    }
    public void GenerateMaze(float hbias,float vbias)
    {
        SetGroups(hbias);
        SetVjoints(vbias);
    }
    public bool[] GetHorizontalJoints()
    {
        return Hjoints;
    }
    public bool[] GetVerticalJoints()
    {
        return Vjoints;
    }
}
public class RowManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject[] Hwalls;
    [SerializeField] GameObject[] Vwalls;
    MazeLogic ml;
    void Awake()
    {
        ml = new MazeLogic();
    }
    void Start()
    {
        Hwalls = new GameObject[4];
        Vwalls = new GameObject[5];
        for (byte i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            Hwalls[i] = transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
        for (byte i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            Vwalls[i] = transform.GetChild((byte)(i+4)).gameObject;
    }
    public void GenerateRow(float hbias,float vbias)
    {
        ml.GenerateMaze(hbias,vbias);
        for (byte i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            if (ml.GetHorizontalJoints()[i])
                Hwalls[i].SetActive(false);
        for(byte i=0;i<5;i++)
            if (ml.GetVerticalJoints()[i])
                Vwalls[i].SetActive(false);//line 155
    }
    public void Reset()
    {
        for (byte i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                Hwalls[i].SetActive(true);
        for (byte i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                Vwalls[i].SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

and array is also not null
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cZlA.png)

Comment: The number of times the system incorrectly raises an index out of bounds error is, for all intents and purposes, zero, as compared against the number of times a programmer has incorrectly asserted that of course their access isn't out of bounds when it turns out it is. Debug and verify which of your assumptions turns out incorrect.

Comment: Are you sure `Start()` is called before you call `GenerateRow`?

Comment: Please provide only the **relevant** parts of your code and where specifically you get the error.

Comment: `[SerializeField] GameObject[] Vwalls;` this line, by means of (de)serialization, initializes `Vwalls` as new `GameObject[0]`. So accessing this array via index operator before calling `Start()` will produce this 100% of the time.

**TL;DR**: do not serialize this array.

Comment: _"Index was outside the bounds of the array. **While Clearly it wasn't**"_ - _["The First Rule of Programming: It's Always Your Fault"](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/)_

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why Hwalls and Vwalls have to be [SerializeField] ?
If not, I would suggest removing that, since they are initialized in your Start() method and not by the user in the Editor. It could fix your problem.

As an aside, I would invite you to separate each class in their own file, making everything way more readable, and allowing you to scroll less.